# 404 error on my homepage although I can see my site

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am at my wits end with the following problem:

My site [www.sebastianthalhammer.com](https://www.sebastianthalhammer.com) is available under that URL without any problems.

However Google Search Console as well as other external third party test tools return a 404 error.

[Status report from Uptrends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGfow.png)

It is just the main page that's affected. All the other subpages and blog content isn't affected.

I have been in contact with the server stuff but it seems alright to them. As mentioned. The site can be reached. The site runs on wordpress - latest version.

I have no real clue where to start as this error seems to be quite a tricky one. Does anyone here might have an idea what's going on?

Sebastian

Comment: Even the developer console of browser show 404 for your page.

Comment: but you could access the page, couldn't you @zipkundan?

Comment: Yes. The page loaded, but there was also 404 error for the page. Interestingly, the 404 error was only for the page and not for any of the linked resourses. I was thinking through it but could not figure out what could have caused this.

Answer (score 0):

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the
>   client seems to have erred. Except when responding to a HEAD
>   request, the server SHOULD include a representation containing an
>   explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or
>   permanent condition. These status codes are applicable to any
>   request method. User agents SHOULD display any included
>   representation to the user.

This leaves me with two possible explanations:

**Explanation 1: it's a server error.**

the server wrongly returns a 404 status code
the browser thinks the response body contains details about the error and displays it - for the end user this is the actual page

**Explanation 2: it's done on purpose to defeat crawlers and page watchers.**

the server returns 404 on purpose - non-browser user agents won't process the result as they interpret it as error
browsers are unaffected, the end user doesn't care as long as the page is being displayed
The second one would indeed be kind of clever if you don't want your page to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your feedback I could think about the problem in a different way.

Ultimately at the unholy depths of a certain plugin I could dig out a setting that caused the error.

It was a redirection plugin that (for whatever reason) sent out a 404 signal when the URL was requested.

I don't know what the purpose would be for something. All I know is that the setting was on default for quite a while now and that caused the weird situation.

thanks guys for getting me on the right track.

Sebastian